# Is it good practice to call a function multiple times in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function

I have this code where I need to call a function multiple times.

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
    centerBox();
}); 

$(window).scroll(function() {
    centerBox();
}); 

centerBox();
```

And I realise this is incredibly messy. Is there any better way to write this?

Comment: That highly depends upon What you do inside centerBox() ? plz provide more information...

Comment: I thought that was the point of using functions. Instead of having all of the code that is inside of `centerBox()` in multiple locations, you just call `centerBox()`.

Comment: you need to execute this in serial way, so when one event fires the other must wait untill it finishes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can shrink your code to 3 lines:

```
$(window).resize(centerBox);
$(window).scroll(centerBox);
centerBox();
```

And of course you have to define your function on top

Or you also can use it in 2 lines by combining it, but that would also be a little messy:

```
$(window).resize(centerBox).scroll(centerBox);
centerBox();
```

Comment: *"And of course you have to define your function on top"* Not if it's a function *declaration*. Only if it's a function expression.

Comment: And you can combine the first two lines: `$(window).resize(centerBox).scroll(centerBox);` or `$(window).bind("resize scroll", centerBox);`

Answer (score 4):

```
var f = function() {
    centerBox();
};

$(window).resize(f).scroll(f);
f();
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's messy; it describes exactly what you want to do. That said, you could shorten it down to:

```
$(window).resize(centerBox).scroll(centerBox);
centerBox();
```

and further to

```
$(window).resize(centerBox).scroll(centerBox).trigger('resize');
```

and even further to

```
$(window).on("resize scroll", centerBox).trigger('resize');
```

since [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) supports binding to multiple events if their names are space-separated.

Answer (score 2):

You could bind + call;

```
$(window).on("scroll resize", centerBox).scroll();
```